# How do I INSERT data from jquery textBox into MySql database using Foreach in Php, or any other way to accomplish this goal?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql

I need the following to happen:

> 1. A form with multiple input boxes that receives user information.
> 2. An "Add User" button that allows for additional user input.
> 3. A submit button that will INSERT the data from the form into the designated database column, and creates a new row in the database for
>      each new user.

I'm very new, and don't know how to loop the `$_REQUEST` array on the **results.php** page to do this. I am open to any suggestions. Thank you in advance.

```js
    var fname, lname, dob, input, inputCount = 0;

  $(window).load(function() {
    newUser();
  })

  function newUser() {
    $('#box >div').hide();
    inputCount++;
    input = $('<div data-id="' + inputCount + '">Entry ' + inputCount + '<br><br></div>').appendTo('#box');
    fname = $('<input type="text" name="fname' + inputCount + '" placeholder="First Name ' + inputCount + '"><br><br>').appendTo(input);
    lname = $('<input type="text" name="lname' + inputCount + '" placeholder="Last Name ' + inputCount + '"><br><br>').appendTo(input);
    dob = $('<input type="text" name="dob' + inputCount + '" placeholder="Date Of Birth ' + inputCount + '"><br><br>').appendTo(input);
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="results.php" method="post">

  <body>
    <span id="box"></span>
    <button type="button" onclick="newUser()">Add User</button>
    <br>
    <br>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
  </body>
</form>
```

Comment: it is `$_POST` and not `$_REQUEST` in php. Also add the server side code and point out the exact problem.

Comment: Please, don't use bold text all over your post.

Answer (score 0):

Your request is sent to PHP. It is mistaken to search for request parameters in `$_REQUEST`. You need to search them in `$_POST`.

You need to define a `name` attribute to your form fields to be passed. In your `newUser` javascript function add the new user's data into the form html. With jQuery, you would do something like `$("#box").append(<your code>)`.

Your code should be something like an `input`, which has a `name` and the needed value. Then, parse the value(s) with the given name at results.php and insert the necessary values.

Comment: Just use the $_POST array. If the name of the form element is name="foobar", then at results.php you can get its value with $_POST["foobar"]

Comment: Where I am stuck at is, each time the Add User button is clicked, $_POST["foobar"] would have multiple entries. How would I parse, or increment  "foobar" so that it represents the additional entries?

Comment: Can you give me an example?

Comment: With the code I have here, every time a person clicks the Add User button,  there will be a new First Name, Last Name, and Date of Births. If the user clicks 5 times, the will be 5 -  First Name, Last Name, and Date of Births, that need to be parsed. In results.php there would be $_POST["fname"], $_POST["lname"], and $_POST["dob"]. Each POST would have 5 entries, under the same key after the Submit button is pressed.

Comment: Yes, the results from the form would be in a useful index.

Comment: Then check which user data should be inserted and which should be not. Insert those, which should be inserted.